# How to create and manage plugins in ASP.NET Core MVC 1.0?

Tags: asp.net, plugins, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Since Asp.Net significantly redesigned it's architecture,we are totally blank regarding how we could create plugins and manage it on our asp.net mvc 6 applications as we could do it easily prior mvc5.We would be grateful if you could provide us an example.

Comment: What do you mean by a plugin?

Comment: I hereby Plugins means Modules so that we could add different features to the existing system.

Comment: Read about " View Components" in mvc 6. http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/vc

Comment: specifically what kind of modules (httpmodules, child actions, etc etc)

Comment: Hereby modules means the features that could be extenteded to the existing application.Since we are making an ecommerce application if we need to add new features we need to create a module and install in the application.We will have the store of modules from where our users could download and install in their applications.

Answer (score 1):

OrchardCMS 2 is developing a modular application framework for asp.net core mvc but I think it is still a work in progress. One to watch for the future. See https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard2/pull/530 for some code and more information is in this video: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/On-NET/Sbastien-Ros-Modular-ASPNET-apps